# From a source angular application when try to proxy a target angular application by angular proxyconf, it still serves the resources of source app

Tags: angular, iframe, cross-domain, reverse-proxy

1. I have 2 angular application runs in the development mode via ng serve.
2. From the first application i'm trying to display the second application
3. So I proxy the target to second application.Once the application runs, in the network tab I can see the response of second application index.html , but the resource files such as polyfills.js, main.js , runtime.js etc running with respect to first application.Because of this second application is not get loaded.

I have tried base href path is same for both application. It is set "/". Also checked the proxy file configuration are set properly or not